# UIWebView not evaluating javascript properly

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I'm trying to run some javascript against a UIWebView but it's doesn't seem to be working. For example, here is a snippet of html I'm using to test:

```
<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1><p>It's me.</p></body></html>
```

If I run the following javascript against it, the return value is 0, when it should be 1.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
elements.length;
```

Here's the objc code I'm using for the webview. 'parser' is a string containing the above javascript:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1><p>It's me.</p></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
NSString *markupResult = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:parser];
```

Answer (score 4):

Implement the UIWebViewDidfinishLoading method and write following code inside it

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *markupResult = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:parser];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Upon further investigation, the problem turned out to be that webview hadn't finished loading when the javascript was called. I had to call the javascript from the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate callback.